# How to run NUnit tests without Visual Studio and Source code?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, nunit

I am very new to Unit-Testing.

I have a solution with C# project. I added to it a new NUnit project and added some tests.

I can run my tests using Test Explorer of Visual Studio, and even using Command-Line in the developing platform:

```
D:\Project\GuiTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1>dotnet test GuiTests.dll
```

I want to do a similar thing, but on a **testing** platform, which does not have Visual Studio and the source code.

I want to copy there only the tests folder (i.e. D:\Project\GuiTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1) and run the tests using Command-Line.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Currently, I tried it out and got:

[image]

===

I tried using nunit-console and got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.10.1.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its
> dependencies.

[image]

Googling it, seems nunit-console does not support .Net Core.

So I think I should go on with the `dotnet test`

Comment: use nunit-console

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation of [NUnit Console Command Line](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html)

> The console interface runner is invoked by a command in the form
> `NUNIT3-CONSOLE [inputfiles] [options]`
> where inputfiles is one or more assemblies or test projects of a type that NUnit can process and
> options is zero or more options. Input files and options may be mixed in any order.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: In issue [Add support for producing XML test results](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/323) recomended to use `dotnet test --logger:trx` on Windows and Linux